# UI design suggestions in android

Tags: android

I am developing an android app with material design which has 2 tab views.
Each tab contains data arranged by categories.

I want to show the categories in left side navigation drawer.On selection of category I will update the list in tab.

Whenever the tab is charged i will change the categories in drawer.
Is this is fine according to the android UI specifications?

Answer (score 2):

I dont know of any restrictions regarding your design choice. I say go for it!